# handle success/error responses http request angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have in my app.js a factory called UserService that does all the user HTTP requests for me.

When I try to create a user I have the following method.

```
function create(user) {
  return $http.post(envService.read('apiUrl') + '/auth/register', user).then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error creating user'));
}
```

Then In my controller I do something like this:

```
function register() {
  vm.dataLoading = true;
  UserService.create(vm.user).then(function successCallback(response) {
      $location.path('/');
      Flash.create('success', response.message);
  }, function errorCallback(error) {
      Flash.create('danger', error);
      vm.dataLoading = false;
  });
}
```

functions to handle success and error

```
  // private functions

  function handleSuccess(res) {
      return res.data;
  }

  function handleError(error) {
      return function () {
          return { success: false, message: error };
      };
  }
```

However, it always goes into the success callback even though the response code is a 403 or anything else that results in an error. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: your `handleError` is being invoked immediately. Arguments of `then` must be functions

Comment: Should the `post` not look similar to this? ► `return $http.post(envService.read('apiUrl') + '/auth/register', user).then(handleSuccess, function(){handleError('Error creating user')});`

Comment: @Fran those are jQuery `$.ajax` callbacks

Comment: @charlietfl how do I fix this?

Comment: @charlietfl I see, never mind me then :) - I corrected it above which I think looks right now...

Comment: for starters show us `handleError` code

Comment: @charlietfl this is all the code, see the errorCallback function in the 2nd code portion

Comment: so there are no actual functions declared for `handleSuccess` and `handleError `?

Comment: @charlietfl ah I see what you mean, yes I have updated the code with the functions I use for that

Comment: so when you return in the error handler that resolves the promise and you would then have to check `success` property in your next `then()` in controller ... or return a promise rejection ... like `return $q.reject(error)`

Answer (score 0):

In Angular JS, when you provide callback functions for '$http', you can either choose not to set the parameter to the functions like

```
$http.get('/someUrl', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

or you provide the functions with callbacks inside them like

```
$http({
method: 'GET',
url: '/someUrl'
    }).then(
       function successCallback(response) {}, 
       function errorCallback(response) {}
       );
```

On the other hand, if you do want to call your own function in the call back, You can choose this way,

```
      $http(
      {
        method: this.url.method,
        url: serviceURL,
      }
      ).
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          successCallback(data, status, headers, config);
      }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
         errorCallback(data, status, headers, config);
      });
```

So, basically your callback function expects a 'response' parameter which contains

1. **data** – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
2. **status** – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
3. **headers** – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
4. **config** – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
5. **statusText** – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

In your code, I would change the 
       `handleError('Error creating user')` with some proper callback and also receive that object in the callback.

for a detailed understanding, read [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: so if I obviously choose the first way, not to set the parameters. Can I do the following function create(user) {
          return $http.post(envService.read('apiUrl') + '/auth/register', user);
      } and handle the callbacks in my controller like I do now?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, but in that case your callback inside your controller should have a 'response' object as a parameter.